# get value count in an array with smarty

Tags: php, smarty

I have an array called `$mydata` that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1282
         [type] =>2

        )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1281
        [type] =>1
        )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1266
          [type] =>2
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1265
        [type] =>3
    )
)
```

I've assigned the array to smarty `$smarty->assign("results", $mydata)`

Now, in the template, I need to print how much of each "type" there is in the array. Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: will there always be an index for type in each element in the array?
and do you want to count all of them or just those with a value higher than zero?

Comment: yes, there will. And the values are always higher than zero.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**PHP 5.3, 5.4:**

As of Smarty 3 you can do

```
{count($mydata)}
```

You can also pipe it in Smarty 2 or 3:

```
{$mydata|count}
```

To count up "type" values you'll have to walk through the array in either PHP or Smarty:

```
{$type_count = array()}
{foreach $mydata as $values}
    {$type = $values['type']}
    {if $type_count[$type]}
        {$type_count[$type] = $type_count[$type] + 1}
    {else}
        {$type_count[$type] = 1}
    {/if}
{/foreach}

Count of type 2: {$type_count[2]}
```

**PHP 5.5+:**

With PHP 5.5+ and Smarty 3 you can use the new `array_column` function:

```
{$type_count = array_count_values(array_column($mydata, 'type'))}
Count of type 2: {$type_count['2']}
```

Comment: I do have Smarty 3, but how do I get the various numbers of "type" from {count($mydata)} ?

Answer (score 24):

have you tried this?:

```
{$mydata|@count}
```

where count is passing the php function count()

Comment: It worked for me...but what is difference between **|count** and **|@count**

Comment: @Poonam Bhatt,
I actually don't know, when I answered this question I just did some research, coded a few lines and figured this, and that was quite a while ago

Comment: @PoonamBhatt quote: `The "@" applies the modifier directly to the array instead of each individual element.` see: [Smarty FAQ](http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=SmartyFrequentlyAskedQuestions#template-1)

Comment: So, to work as expected, should use @count to count an array… Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use:

```
{if $myarray|@count gt 0}...{/if}
```